# Homemade keyboard with microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, usb-device

I want to make completely on my own a keyboard with maximum 6 keys with a USB connection.  Can someone tell me what microcontroller should I buy and what specification should I look for?

Comment: Any microcontroller with USB capability will do. You can easily do this with an Arduino, or the ATMega CPU its based on. Low speed USB can also be done entirely in firmware in chips as small as an ATTiny. A single ATTiny85 (8 pin package) can do a 4 button HID with USB trivially, and with some cleverness 8 buttons would certainly be possible.

Comment: My [answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/13666/1494) to a related (but not duplicate!) question has some links. Look at the other answers too.

Comment: We have no idea what your skills or experience are.  For some this would be a trivial project, for others it could takes months and go nowhere.

Comment: I am knew with this projects.I know a little about MIPS and circuits but i want to get in this.I want the lowest price and arduino rises it and wont let me learn how to program microcontrollers.

Comment: @user3247715: OK you don't want to use an Arduino - that's fine, but the reasons you give are not bulletproof. An Arduino clone or mini can cost less than $9. Programming an Atmel AVR microcontroller with the Arduino IDE still counts as programming a microcontroller. If you are averse to using the Arduino IDE or libraries, you can program an Arduino using the standard Atmel AVR toolset (or any other).

Comment: what board do you reccomend?  Adruino Uno is good for what i want?

Comment: You want one with native USB device support. This means Leonardo or Esplora unless you feel up to reprogramming the communication chip in the Uno or Due.

Comment: what do you mean with native support USB device? Sorry now i learn them. Leonardo seems better to me cause the other has buttons on its own.

Comment: Look in the datasheet for the MCU. Find the part that says "USB device support" (or something to that effect). If the MCU has it then it can act as a USB device without emulation libraries or intervening chips.

Comment: I hacked [these](http://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/prjhid.html) two [projects](http://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/prjdetail.php?pid=64) into a 4 key audio controller for my PC. There are several inspiring projects on that site, most with low component count and friendly priced devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on your experience with microcontrollers and also budget you have.
If cost is no issue, any USB capable MCU will do.
If you want to do it as cheap as possible, you can use some AVR MCUs even without HW USB. You can use this library [VUSB](http://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/index.html), which creates SW USB on your AVR device.
You can make your keybord electronics below 5$ with such setup.

Here are some articles about using this library:
[Tutorial](http://codeandlife.com/2012/01/22/avr-attiny-usb-tutorial-part-1/)
[HackADay](http://hackaday.com/2013/10/23/serial-usb-for-any-avr-microcontroller/)

I'm sure there are similar libraries for other MCU's from other manufacturers.

Comment: I think i am gonna try this.And do you know any good online book to understand microcontrollers cause i dont know what are all this pins doing.